# kernel timed out for large array when X Server is on

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am launching my kernel and checking for possible errors as follows:

```
kernel<<<grid,block>>>(d_Basis, d_repul_aux,nao);
  cout<<"done with the ERIs...."<<endl;
  std::string error = cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  cout<<error<<endl;

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(eris_gpu_cpu_aux.data(),d_repulsion_aux,eris_size*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

where cudaGetErrorString(cudaPeekAtLastError()) is used in order to do error checking for the kernel and I have defined:

```
static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                         const char *file,
                         int line ) {
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {
    printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
            file, line );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
```

When the X server is off, the computation runs as spected; but if I turn on the X server, the kernel hangs out and I get the following output:

```
done with the ERIs....
no error
the launch timed out and was terminated in main.cu at line 1038
```

The line 1038 in the source code corresponds to:

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(eris_gpu_cpu_aux.data(),d_repulsion_aux,eris_size*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

What means that the computation crashes when we are copying the results from the device  to the host. I am using a graphic card GEforce GTx-480, and CUDA 7.5 .

Attempting to solve the problem, I tried to turn off the "Interactive" option in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file but the X server  does not recognize this option. What can I do in order to share the GPU resources between the X Server  and my GPGPU application? I insist on this because is unconfortable for me to write and/or debug my code using text mode enviroment.

Comment: The error in the cudaMemcpy following the kernel is actually a failure of the kernel to complete successfully.   You should follow the instructions [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).  Your statements about the X server not recognizing that option don't make sense.  That option is handled by the NVIDIA GPU driver, not the X server.  So my guess would be that you did not modify the xorg.conf correctly, or else you modified an xorg.conf file that your X-server is not even using for display configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, in fact, I used the wrong sintaxys  to  turn off  the interactive option, an example of the right syntaxis  can be found  [here.](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/hpc-visualization-nvidia-tesla-gpus/)

Comment: So the problem is fixed?

Comment: If you want to provide an answer showing a snippet of the changes you made to your xorg.conf, it would probably be useful for other readers.  I would upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous  /etc/X11/xorg.conf file were as follows:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 319.21  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-14)  Sun May 12 00:46:48 PDT 2013


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

In order to solve  the problem  we have to disable watchdog timeouts as follows:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 319.21  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-14)  Sun May 12 00:46:48 PDT 2013


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
##
##  disable watchdog timeouts for long-running CUDA kernels
##
    Option "Interactive" "false"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```